# How to identify the first occurence of duplicate rows in Python pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with duplicate values for a set of columns. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'Column2': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'XYZ', 2: 'ABC'}, 'Column3': {0: 'DEF', 1: 'DEF', 2: 'DEF'}, 'Column4': {0: 10, 1: 40, 2: 10})

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   Column1 Column2 Column3  Column4 is_duplicated  dup_index
0        1     ABC     DEF       10         False          0
1        2     XYZ     DEF       40         False          1
2        3     ABC     DEF       10          True          0
```

*Row (1) and (3) are same. Essentially, Row (3) is a duplicate of Row (1).*

I am looking for the following output:

`Is_Duplicate`, containing whether the row is a duplicate or not [can be accomplished by using "duplicated" method on dataframe columns (Column2, Column3 and Column4)]

`Dup_Index` the original index of the duplicate row.

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   Column1 Column2 Column3  Column4  Is_Duplicate  Dup_Index
0        1     ABC     DEF       10         False          0
1        2     XYZ     DEF       40         False          1
2        3     ABC     DEF       10          True          0
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a DataFrame method [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for the first column:

```
In [11]: df.duplicated(['Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4'])
Out[11]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True

In [12]: df['is_duplicated'] = df.duplicated(['Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4'])
```

To do the second you could try something like this:

```
In [13]: g = df.groupby(['Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4'])

In [14]: df1 = df.set_index(['Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4'])

In [15]: df1.index.map(lambda ind: g.indices[ind][0])
Out[15]: array([0, 1, 0])

In [16]: df['dup_index'] = df1.index.map(lambda ind: g.indices[ind][0])

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
   Column1 Column2 Column3  Column4 is_duplicated  dup_index
0        1     ABC     DEF       10         False          0
1        2     XYZ     DEF       40         False          1
2        3     ABC     DEF       10          True          0
```

Comment: Thank you, @AndyHayden. I am am looking for some thing like this to solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103097/load-multiple-csv-files-look-for-missing-merchandiseid-in-subsequent-files-cal . Instead of the setting the dup_index to the original occurrence, is there a way to get the last occurrence and set a column value there? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thank you got it, used df1.index.map(lambda ind: g.indices[ind][len(g.indices[ind])-1])

Comment: @Alice glad you got it sorted. Apologies I wasn't out to help earlier: I did look at the question but wasn't able to quite understand / dig in at the time.

Comment: Thank you @AndyHayden for the pointers. One more question, any way to blank out or not have all the entries in the 'dup-index' column filled, other than the last occurrence of the row. So none of the 'dup_index' columns will have any value other than the last occurrence of the row. Also posted as  a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188701/how-to-identify-and-set-a-column-value-for-only-the-last-occurrence-of-a-duplica

Answer (score 4):

Let's say your dataframe is stored in `df`.

You can use [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) to get non duplicated rows of your dataframe. Here we have to ignore Column1 that is not part of the data:

```
df_nodup = df.groupby(by=['Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4']).first()
```

you can then merge this new dataframe with the original one by using the [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function:

```
df = df.merge(df_nodup, left_on=['Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4'], right_index=True, suffixes=('', '_dupindex'))
```

You can eventually use the _dupindex column merged in the dataframe to make the simple math to add the columns needed:

```
df['Is_Duplicate'] = df['Column1']!=df['Column1_dupindex']
df['Dup_Index'] = None
df['Dup_Index'] = df['Dup_Index'].where(df['Column1_dupindex']==df['Column1'], df['Column1_dupindex'])
del df['Column1_dupindex']
```