# Load multiple csv files, look for missing merchandiseID in subsequent files, calculate the date sold based on it

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am relatively new to Pandas and Python, so pardon me if this is a basic question. I looked around, but could not find a solution.

I have multiple csv files, one for each month, which among other things have:

```
inventory_01312017.csv
store_id stock_number merchandise_id date_acquired color price MSRP photo url
 12973     7382        UISN78008     04/11/2017     Red  $3200 $3650 ...
 45973     9889        YHAN79807     08/09/2017    White $3600 $3650 ...

inventory_02282017.csv
store_id stock_number merchandise_id date_acquired color price MSRP photo url
 45973     9889        YHAN79807     08/09/2017    White $3600 $3650 ...
```

I need to load these files, which I was able to do without any issues using

```
import pandas as pd 
...
prep_data1 = pd.read_csv("../data/inventory_0131170401.csv")
prep_data2 = pd.read_csv("../data/inventory_0201170456.csv")
prep_data = pd.concat([prep_data1, prep_data2], ignore_index=True)
...
prep_data['age_months'] = age_count(prep_data['date_acquired']) #Adding a new column to get integer value for age
```

Now, I have to scan these files and figure out when a particular item with a merchandise_id was sold and create a new column in the data frame and put it in the last csv it appears. If a item was sold, then it will not be in stock for that month and will not show up in that month's inventory csv file.

For example, if the item was sold in Jan2018, it will not show up in the inventory file for Feb2018. I have to add this data to Jan2018's data frame or csv. Added an example above, in which case I should add a column in the first csv file, something like this:

```
inventory_01312017.csv
store_id stock_number merchandise_id date_acquired color price MSRP  date_sold
 12973     7382        UISN78008     04/11/2017    Red  $3200 $3650  01/31/2017
 45973     9889        YHAN79807     08/09/2017   White $3600 $3650
```

I need this data to be able to find out how long the item is in stock before it is sold (diff between data_acquired and date_sold) and how it affects its pricing. 
I thought about doing this manually, but it will take me weeks to finish this for so many files and its will be an ongoing effort.

If I missed out any information to solve, please let me know. I can update. 
Update:
I updated with some sample data and code. Hope that makes my question a bit clearer.
Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

best,

Alice

Comment: A Sample of data would be nice...

Comment: To echo @DJK: we want to help! Just give us some data :) (and preferably the code you have so far)

Comment: Hint: add `month` to your data structure, consider it as a database with a table built from **all** your .csv files, having columns `month, merchandise_id, date_acquired, date_sold....`. Rephrase your task in more formal way using the field names - what are the condition(s) to be met, to change the `date_sold` field. Then just code it. Good luck.