# How to identify and set a column value for only the last occurrence of a duplicate row

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to Pandas and Python, so pardon me if this is a basic question. In an effort to solve my problem: [Load multiple csv files, look for missing merchandiseID in subsequent files, calculate the date sold based on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103097/load-multiple-csv-files-look-for-missing-merchandiseid-in-subsequent-files-cal), I made some changes to how I clean these files. I have the following columns in the data frame loaded from multiple csv files.

```
store_id stock_number merchandise_id date_acquired color price MSRP csv_date
12973     7382        UISN78008     04/11/2017    Red  $3200 $3650  01/31/2017
45973     9889        YHAN79807     08/09/2017   White $3600 $3650  01/31/2017
...
45973     9889        YHAN79807     08/09/2017   White $3600 $3650  03/31/2017
```

The last column is the last occurrence of the item with merchandise_id 'YHAN79807'. I was able to find the last occurrence, by following [How to identify the first occurence of duplicate rows in Python pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952957/how-to-identify-the-first-occurence-of-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas-dataframe) and modifying it a bit. I used

```
 df1['dup_index'] = df1.index.map(lambda ind: g.indices[ind][len(g.indices[ind])-1])
```

However, I want to set this value for the column 'dup_index' only for the last occurrence of 'YHAN79807' as merchandiseID. I do not want the rest of the rows with duplicated data for 'YHAN79807' as merchandiseID to have this value. They should be blank. Only the last occurrence should have this ID. I have not been able to do that yet. I tried a few things, one was:

```
group = df1.groupby(['merchandiseID'])
df1_index = df1.set_index(['merchandiseID'])
df1[ (((len(group.indices[ind])-1)==group.indices[df1.merchandiseID])]['dup_index'] = 'succeed'
```

I tried adding 'succeed' as a first step to see if the column comparison will give me result, but it gave me the following error:

```
 FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
```

result = getattr(x, name)(y) ...
     raise TypeError('Could not compare %s type with Series' %

I am at my wits end. What am I missing? Any pointers are appreciated.

best,

Alice

Comment: How my solution work? Or need something else?

Comment: Thank you so much @jezrael. I will try this later in the day and will let you know for sure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
g = df.groupby(['merchandise_id'])
df1 = df.set_index(['merchandise_id'])
df['dup_index'] = df1.index.map(lambda ind: g.indices[ind][len(g.indices[ind])-1])
print (df)
   store_id  stock_number merchandise_id date_acquired  color  price   MSRP  \
0     12973          7382      UISN78008    04/11/2017    Red  $3200  $3650   
1     45973          9889      YHAN79807    08/09/2017  White  $3600  $3650   
2     45973          9889      YHAN79807    08/09/2017  White  $3600  $3650   

     csv_date  dup_index  
0  01/31/2017          0  
1  01/31/2017          2  
2  03/31/2017          2
```

Or if need identify only last duplicated rows use double conditions with `&`:

```
print (df)
   store_id  stock_number merchandise_id date_acquired  color  price   MSRP  \
0     12973          7382      UISN78008    04/11/2017    Red  $3200  $3650   
1     45973          9889      YHAN79807    08/09/2017  White  $3600  $3650   
2     45973          9889      YHAN79807    08/09/2017  White  $3600  $3650   
3     45973          9889      YHAN79807    08/09/2017  White  $3600  $3650   

     csv_date  
0  01/31/2017  
1  01/31/2017  
2  01/31/2017  
3  03/31/2017  


m1 = ~df.duplicated(['merchandise_id'], keep='last')
m2 = df.duplicated(['merchandise_id'], keep=False)
m = m1 & m2
df.loc[m, 'new'] = 'succeed'
print (df)
   store_id  stock_number merchandise_id date_acquired  color  price   MSRP  \
0     12973          7382      UISN78008    04/11/2017    Red  $3200  $3650   
1     45973          9889      YHAN79807    08/09/2017  White  $3600  $3650   
2     45973          9889      YHAN79807    08/09/2017  White  $3600  $3650   
3     45973          9889      YHAN79807    08/09/2017  White  $3600  $3650   

     csv_date      new  
0  01/31/2017      NaN  
1  01/31/2017      NaN  
2  01/31/2017      NaN  
3  03/31/2017  succeed
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jezrael, that worked like a charm. I had the first one working in my code, but that was not what I wanted. The second solution was what I was looking for. It worked like a charm.